# polymorphism in c and buffers

Tags: c, serialization, buffer, unions, binary-serialization

I have this union:

```
typedef union Message
{
    message_base            base;
    message_with_parameters  parameters;
    reply_message          reply;
    buffer_t                *buffer; // can't figure out what to put here
} message;
```

`message_with_parameters` has a `message_base` as the first field and `reply_message` has a `message_with_parameters` as as the first field which in turns has `message_base` as as the first field.
So basically I can access any of them and I'll still get all the data I need, however I am getting a buffer from my driver and now I want to serialize it into the message.
I already know that the pointer to the buffer is wrong as it won't correlate with my structs but I can't have a fixed size buffer.
Somewhere along the way I want to do this:

```
m->buffer = buff->payload;
```

And no matter what kind of data type I have, it will still serialize.
How can it be done?

EDIT:
Here are my structs:

```
typedef struct MessageBase
{
    uint32_t    u32DeviceID;
    uint32_t    u32CoreID;
    uint16_t    u16Class;
    uint16_t    u16CRC;
    uint8_t     u8OpCode;

    void (*states [MAX_OPCODES]) (void *);
} message_base;

typedef struct MessageWithParameters
{
    message_base    base_class;
    uint8_t         u8Param1;
    uint8_t         u8Param2;
} message_with_parameters;

typedef message_with_parameters reply_message;

typedef union Message
{
    message_base            base;
    message_with_parameters parameters;
    reply_message           reply;
} message;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its because the data in the buffer isn't part of the union.

buffer_t* buffer   is a pointer,  so the pointer is part of the union, not the data which it points at

you probablly want to do something like

```
 m =  (message*) buff->payload;
```

Comment: I am getting only junk. Even if the values I input are correct.

Comment: its hard to know what you are doing,  I'm just making some guesses.

you have a buffer of data which is a "Message",  so you have defined a message union  ( which I'm a little bit suspicious of, I'm not sure if all those fields are supposed to be a union? or whether it should be a struct with some of those as a union?  ).   therefore your data in your buffer,  the first byte will be the first byte in whatever is in  message base, and also it will be the first byte of reply_message, and also it will be the first byte of message_with parameters.

Comment: @Keith Nicholas: See my edit for my structs.
payload's type is void * in case you were wondering

Comment: so, if you do 

m = (message*) buff->payload

then is m->base.u32DeviceID   something sensible?

I'd be suspicious of the data in payload perhaps.

then

have a look at m->base

Comment: void blah()
{
 unsigned char data[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
 message* m = (message*) data;

 printf("%x\r\n", m->base.u32DeviceID);
}

that prints out "4030201"  for me....

Comment: that was using your structs copy pasted directly

Comment: strangely enough it now works. turns out I assigned a pointer to a pointer somehow and that messed things up. I am accepting this as the right answer since you got me going on the right direction. Thanks.